# Hibernate giving old data when queried

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called Animal which has animalId(pkey) and age. I have added an entry with animalId 1 and age 5.

and a controller which looks like this, when I hit the trigger API expectation is to change the age to 10.
Controller looks like this,

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class TestController {

    private final AnimalService animalService;
    private final TestAnimalService testAnimalService;

    @GetMapping("/trigger")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAnimals() {
        animalService.updateAnimalOuter(1); // call update method using an inner UpdateService
        animalService.queryAnimal(1); // query the age
        return new ResponseEntity<>("success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and AnimalService
I am calling updateAnimalOuter method on AnimalService(note that it has REQUIRES_NEW), which gets the animal by age and calls the updateAnimalInner of UpdateService where the update is actually happening.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnimalService {

    private final AnimalRepository animalRepository;
    private final UpdateService updateService;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateAnimalOuter(int animalId) {
        AnimalEntity animal = animalRepository.findByAnimalId(animalId);
        //check some properties of animal and do some actions, don't udpate anything here
        updateService.updateAnimalInner(animalId); // in this method update
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void queryAnimal(int animalId) {
        AnimalEntity animal = animalRepository.findByAnimalId(animalId);
        Integer age = animal.getAge();
        if (age == 5) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Age is still 5, but the age is 10 in db and this is an new transaction..");
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateService looks like this, which has Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, here I am updating the age to 10.

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UpdateService {

    @Autowired
    private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateAnimalInner(int animalId) {
        AnimalEntity animal = animalRepository.findByAnimalId(animalId);
        animal.setAge(10);
        animalRepository.save(animal);
        log.info("exiting innerMethod");
    }
}
```

I can see that when this method is exited, the age is propery updated to 10 in the database.
Even when it reaches controller, the age is still 10.

When queryAnimal method is called from controller however the age is returned as 5 and exception is thrown `Age is still 5, not updated` but I can still see that the age is 10 in db.

Why is hibernate giving age 5 which is old value when queried?

also note that if I remove `AnimalEntity animal = animalRepository.findByAnimalId(animalId);` from updateAnimalOuter method, it works fine.
I am wondering why this statement causing the query method to return old value even though * it's updated correctly in database * ?

Note: I am using Spring Version 2.5.2 and hibernate 5.4.32 Final

Comment: Because it is cached in the first level cache, it will read the old value. You have 2 transactions and 2 sessions.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am querying in a separate session/transaction right? Not in the same transaction where I did the update.

Comment: Also if I remove AnimalEntity animal = animalRepository.findByAnimalId(animalId); line  from updateAnimalOuter method , why is it not being stored in the cache? I get right value '10' when queried.

Comment: Because it is the find that is making it being retrieved in session 1, the update is in session 2 and then you retrieve again in session 1 (at that moment it comes from the cache). If you don't do a find in session 1, there is nothing in the cache and thus it will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum After the first find in sessoin1 it goes back to controller and session1 is finished (note I don't have transactional in controller method). Now queryAnimal is being called from controller method, so it's session3 right?

Comment: No it isn't as, by default, there is also open-session-in-view in play, so this will be on the same session again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234578/discussion-between-prajwal-and-m-deinum).